# Задача на динамический список

Tags: c++, списки

Создать программу, которая обеспечивает ввод и вывод файл. Осуществить следующие действия:
1. Чтение файла.
2. Чтение целых чисел и помещение их в динамический список.
3. Создание двумерного в массива в дин. памяти; кол-во строк должно быть равно кол-ву целых чисел в файле.
4. Заполнение массива числами из списка, если остаются свободные ячейки, они должны быть заполнены нулями.
5. Removing elements of linked list from free store
Код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

const int n = 3;

struct Link {
    double data;
    Link *next;
};

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    Link *first = NULL;
    Link *link;
    Link *currentNode;
    ifstream fileWithNumbers;
    fileWithNumbers.open("data.txt");
    unsigned int count = 0;
    double d;
    while (!fileWithNumbers.eof() && fileWithNumbers >> d) {
        count++;
        link = new Link;
        link->data = d;
        link->next = 0;
        if (first == NULL) {
            first = link; 
            currentNode = first;
        }
    }
    double **array = new double*[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        array[i] = new double[n];
    }
    link = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            array[i][j] = link->data;
            link->next;
            if (Link* data = NULL) {
                array[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("Кол-во элементов в файле %d\n", count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << array[i][j] << "\t";
        }
    }

    delete[] array;



    _getch();
}
```

Файл data.txt:

```
46 82 11 24
55
34 29
100
```

Вопрос в чем. В файле 8 чисел. Матрица 8х3, весь массив заполняется только числом 46. Я гуглил работу с динамическими списками, там сложные примеры, да еще с применением контейнера list, с которым я вообще не знаком. Помогите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так? Тема довольно таки сложная и тяжело понять некоторые моменты.

Comment: Условия задачи не ясны. Зачем нужен двумерный массив 8х? для хранения 8 чисел, если вполне достаточно одномерного? Откуда Вы берете размер матрицы 8х3 (почему именно 3)?

Comment: @andy.37, это не я беру, это такое мое индивидуальное задание, нужно использовать двумерный массив.

Comment: Уточните этот момент у преподавателя, если это возможно. В такой формулировке задача выглядит банально глупо. Для совсем уж новичка неплохо, кстати... Вся матрица заполнена первым числом потому, что `link->next;` не сдвигает элемент списка.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Когда Вы заполняете изначальный список (цикл `while`), Вы нигде не устанавливаете `link->next`, который должен указывать на следующий элемент в списке
2. Когда Вы заполняете массив `array` (первый вложенный `for`) инструкция `link->next;` не делает ничего. Вот прямо совсем ничего.

Все это должно выглядеть примерно так (внимание: НЕ проверял):

```
int main()
{
    Link *first = NULL;
    Link *currentNode = NULL;
    Link *link;
    ifstream fileWithNumbers;
    fileWithNumbers.open("data.txt");
    unsigned int count = 0;
    double d;
    while (!fileWithNumbers.eof() && fileWithNumbers >> d) {
        count++;
        if (currentNode) { // currentNode уже определен => обрабатываем не первый эл-т
            Link *link = new Link;
            link->data = d;
            link->next = 0;
            currentNode->next = link;
            currentNode = link;
        } else { // создаем первый элемент
            currentNode = new Link;
            currentNode->data = d;
            currentNode->next = NULL;
            first = currentNode;
        }
    }
    link = first;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        array[i][0] = link->data;
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++) {
            array[i][j] = 0;
        }
        link = link->next;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Пропущенные куски кода, вроде бы верны. Зачем здесь нужен двумерный массив, по прежнему не ясно. Если только "количество строк в массиве должно быть равно количеству строк в файле"...

П.С. ЕМНИП, вместо `NULL` лучше использовать `nullptr` или просто `0`.

Comment: Код работающий. Но у меня такой вопрос по теме, не могли бы Вы объяснить, что, так сказать, значит условие в цикле if(currentNode)... ?

Comment: @Overthesanity `if (currentNode)` эквивалентно `if (currentNode != 0)`. Т.к. сначала мы инициализируем `currentNode` нулем, то это условие будет ложным только при первой итерации цикла, когда мы создаем первый эл-т нашего списка.